# Laravel move image from one folder to another with button

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to Laravel and I'm trying to figure out the appropriate way of moving an image with the click of a button. I currently have a folder containing unverified images, and these are displayed on a control panel where admins can approve them before they're displayed on another page.

My current solution is to add a link below the image called 'Accept Image', which passes the image name as a GET parameter to another file. This is sent to another page that moves the image from the unverified folder to the verified folder, and then the admin gets redirected back to the control panel. The solution works just fine, but I'm not sure if this is a safe/good way to do it.

Here's my code:

```
<a href="/accept/upload?fileName='.$fileName.'">Accept Image</a>
```

And the /accept/upload looks like this:

```
$fileName = htmlentities($_GET['fileName']);
$destinationPath = 'verified-images/';
$sourcePath = 'unverified-images/';

if (File::move($sourcePath.$fileName, $destinationPath.$fileName))
{
  Session::flash('success', 'Success'); 
  return Redirect::to('controlpanel');
} 
else
{
  Session::flash('error', 'Error');
  return Redirect::to('controlpanel');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that's all the code but make sure you have some sort of access control so not everyone can do this, otherwise it looks like it would be possible for someone to pass in some variables where they can start moving just about any file around.  I'd also check mimetypes on the files to be sure they are images.

Another solution altogether and one I think more people would prefer is to keep all the files in the same directory where each file would have one corresponding record in a database table which would have columns like path, verified, created, and updated.  Then you'd just need to grab the correct records from the database to display the images.

Comment: Okay, but how can I validate the image if it's just a string I'm passing? If i use Validator::make($fileName, $rules); I get an error saying $fileName must be an array.